# I want to understand how to implement queues

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I am at the beginning of learning to code, so pls dont be strict. I really don't understand Queues, I know the first class is creating a queue if the blanks would be filled and the second one is creating a QueueElement. I don't understand why knowsFirst= null, how to implement dequeue and enqueue. I guess I have understood the basics of enqueue, dequeue etc. and watched videos but they are simply too complicated for me, my school wants me to implement dequeue and enqueue, I guess this whole programm is basically just imported later on. So anyone who could explain it to me (for dummies)?

```
//first class
public class Queue {

    private QueueElement knowsFirst;

    public Queue() {
        knowsFirst = null;
    }

    public void enqueue(Object pObject) {
        if (knowsFirst = null) {
            //what will be here 
        } else {
            //and here?
        }
    }

    public void dequeue() {
        if (knowsFirst != null) {
            // and here?
        }
    }
}
```

```
//second class
public class QueueElement {

    private QueueElement knowsFollower;
    private Object knowsContent;

    public QueueElement(Object pObject) {
        knowsContent = pObject;
        knowsFollower = null;
    }

    public void enqueue(Object pObject) {
        if (knowsFollower = null) {
            //what will be here?
        } else {
            //and here?
        }
    }

    public QueueElement getFollower() {
        return knowsFollower;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend buying a book on data structures and algorithms.

Comment: From the two classes, the queue implementation is similar to a linked list. It would be better if you understand the [linked list data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of queue is known as a *linked list*. The concept is simple: you have a bunch of *nodes*, each containing a reference to the next link in the chain. You might also use a container object, which holds a reference to the *head*, or front of the list.

```
+----------+    +----------+
| Object A | -> | Object B | -> ...
+----------+    +----------+
```

For a queue, you want to be able to add objects to one end (i.e. `enqueue`) and remove them from the other. (i.e. `dequeue`).

### Dequeuing

It's easier to dequeue on the head side, so that will be our dequeuing side. The steps are as follows:

- grab the current head
- set the new head to the next node, if there is any next node
- return the contents of the head node

### Enqueuing

Since we're dequeuing from the head, we need to enqueue from the tail, or end, of the list. If your teacher desires that you use the exact class members provided, the only way to find the end of the list is to start from the head, and follow the chain of pointers until the last node, which does not point to a next node. Alternatively, you can cache a reference, which is far more efficient. Whichever way you find the tail element, the steps are the same:

- create a new element for the tail
- have the current tail element point to this new element, placing it at the end of the chain.
- Ensure that the new tail points to nothing.